# How to get rid of mysterious JSP Problems in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, compiler-errors

I have the following errors in (just) one of the dozens `*.jsp` files we have in our project:

### Eclipse Problems view

[image: Eclipse Problems view]

*line 0* in a text editor is somehow funny, but OK, we devs often start to count there. Does this refer to the small red square top-right (which says "Errors: 8" on hover, BTW)?

### SonarLint Report view

[image: SonarLint Report view]

### Line 115

```xml
                <tr>
                  <td>Status</td>
                  <td>
                    <select name="oid_status">
<!-- Warning here --> <c:forEach 
<!-- This is L115 -->   items='${
                          [
                            ["0",        "---Bitte wählen---"],
                            ["active",   "aktiv"], 
                            ["assigned", "zugewiesen"], 
                            ["retired",  "zurückgestellt"], 
                            ["invalid",  "ungültig"]
                          ] 
                        }' 
                        var="option"
                      >
                        <option 
                          value="${option[0]}" 
                          ${searchCriteria.status() eq option[0] ? "selected" : ""}
                        >${option[1]}</option>
                      </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

### Line 161

```xml
                <tr>
                  <td>Kategorie</td>
                  <td>
                    <select name="oid_category">
 <!-- Warning here --><c:forEach 
 <!-- This is L161 -->  items='${
                          [
                            ["0",        "---Bitte wählen---"],
                            ["alias", "Alias (alias)"],
                            ["other", "Andere (other)"],
                            ["document", "Dokument (document)"],
                            ["experimental", "Experimentell (experimental)"],
                            ["external", "Extern (external)"],
                            ["identificationscheme", "Identifikationsschema (identificationscheme)"],
                            ["instance-identifier", "Instanz Identifikator (instance-identifier)"],
                            ["codingscheme", "Kodierschema (codingscheme)"],
                            ["organization", "Organization (organization)"],
                            ["person", "Person (person)"],
                            ["policy", "Richtlinie (policy)"],
                            ["service", "Service (service)"], 
                            ["template", "Vorlage (template)"],
                            ["valueset", "Value Set (valueset)"]
                          ] 
                        }' 
                        var="option"
                      >
                        <option 
                          value="${option[0]}" 
                          ${searchCriteria.category() eq option[0] ? "selected" : "" }
                        >${option[1]}</option>
                      </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

It's consistently wrong, at least. These are the only such constructs in the file.

I updated the (Maven) project dozens of times. I cleaned the project (with both *Eclipse* ➔ *Project* ➔ *Clean...* and `mvn clean`). I `-clean`ed the workspace on Eclipse's startup. I even created a new workspace, abandoned the old one and imported all projects newly. I also performed a few Eclipse updates already since this occurred. All to no avail. I have a colleague who knows much more about JSP than me, but even he has no idea. And yes, every (Maven) build succeeds and the webapp runs without issues (apart from usual dev or environment hickups).

Comment: It's consistently wrong, noway to improve it. The data can be loaded using Ajax.

Comment: @RomanC Thx for your reply, Can, you however be a bit more specific. What's exactly wrong? Eclipse's JSP syntax validator? The JSP syntax in the file (perhaps outdated for newer SW versions)? Who can't improve it? The Eclipse plugin devs? I regarding the file content? Which data are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the commentarie the JSP syntax is constantly wrong. The errors are correct.

```xml
<c:forEach 
 <!-- This is L161 -->  items='${
```

This is already wrong, because you cannot use comments in the JSP tags.

Then for `items` attribute the iterable object is expected, but `[` is found in the JSP expression.

For some languages like OGNL the JSP editor sometimes fails to validate a syntax. This is not only Eclipse editor but IntelliJ IDEA also fails because it's impossible to correctly validate the unknown language for JSP editor. At runtime no error happens, since that always turned off JSP syntax checker. But this is not your case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The comments are just for clarification in the Q here. They are NOT in the real source. Wasn't that obvious? We didn't create these files. We inherited them from a project which was developed ~10 yrs. ago. And as always, the people left long ago and as sometimes they didn't leave a single line of unit test. You are right. Everything's fine at runtime. What makes me wonder is that my colleague doesn't and didn't get these msgs in Eclipse on his machine.

Comment: Who knows, Eclipse is an open source IDE, and can be extended with the custom plugin, but this is not a point, the code inside the `<forEach>` tag is not a valid EL expression or is not a standard EL. As for me I do not prefer any data to be prerendered in html because of size of html, Ajax is the only way. More over if the data is pagable then it's impossible at all.